# how to solve Session not affected by update of database

Tags: php, html, session

i have a problem of updating the echo of session after the database is updated can you help me with this

this image is the example [before update of database][1]

then this is after databse is updated 
[after database is updated][2]

can you help me with this problem

the session there is the name which is in example is Joel Masangcay before i updated by after i updated the session must show try ko which is the first name and last name that i updated.

this is the codes of that display session

```
            echo " " . $_SESSION["name"] .  " " . $_SESSION["lname"] .  "  ";

            ?></li>
```

the codes of update

```
<?php
session_start();
$try = $_SESSION['login_user'];

 if(isset($_SESSION["login_user"]))
 {

 }

else

{
   header('location: indexmain.php');  
}

 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
            if(isset($_SESSION["company_name"])&&isset($_SESSION["name"]))

                $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mcndb");

                $kompanes = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_SESSION["company_name"]);
             $user = $_SESSION["user"];
                  $fsname=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["fname"]);
                     $lsname=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["lnames"]);
                    $mdname=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["mname"]);

              $sql2 = "UPDATE tbltry SET firstname='{$fsname}' , lastname = '{$lsname}',middlename ='{$mdname}' WHERE id = {$user}";

      if ($connection->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Successfully updated")';
        echo '</script>';
} 
                else {

        echo '<script>';

        echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $connection->error;
        echo 'alert("try again?")';
        echo '</script>';

}    

}
?>
```

Comment: No idea, you've some code for us, instead of just screenshots?

Comment: May be something wrong with what updated values are your trying to set may be wrong! showing your code will only be the way instead!

Comment: @ShashankShah the update code is success but the problem is that the session will not refresh even i refresh the browser. it will only refresh after i log out and login again, i dont know what to do

Comment: @Fred-ii- there i updated my question and put the codes

Comment: I don't where these are assigned anywhere `$_SESSION["name"] $_SESSION["lname"]`. Then I see `$_POST["lnames"]` which could be associated with it. Best to check for errors here. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, view your HTML source and use `var_dump():` to see what's set or not. Best I can do for you here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the $_SESSION["name"] $_SESSION["lname"] is from my login page which all my session came from and the $_POST["lnames"] is used to get the data from my input type text which name is lnames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your session variables with the new values.
Enter this in your IF statement on successful DB update

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'alert("Successfully updated")';
echo '</script>';
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["fname"];
$_SESSION["lname"] = $_POST["lnames"];
```

Comment: thanks i will try it now

Comment: Thanks its okay now very helpful answer